# Booleans not returning correctly

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

My task is to be able to the an someones birthday as an argument and return there age and whether or not its there birthday in this specific way

getBirthDate('09/06/1992'); // returns array('age' => 21, 'birthday' => true);

I can't get the booleans to work right because it always returns the else statement even though the if statement is true.

```
<?php
function getBirthDate($birthdate)
{

$today =getdate();
$day =array($today["mon"], $today["mday"]);
$newBday = str_replace("/",",",$birthdate);
$birthDate = explode(",",$newBday);
$monthDay = array($birthDate["0"],$birthDate[1]);
$compared = array_diff($day,$monthDay);
if ($compared == ""){
    $age = ($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"]);

        $dateArray = array( "age" => "$age", "birthday" => "True");
        return print_r ($dateArray);
        return True;
}   
else{
    if ($monthDay[0] < $day[0]){
        $age = (($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"])-1);
        $dateArray = array( "age" => "$age", "birthday" => "False");
        return print_r($dataArray);
        return True;

                             }
    else{
        $age = (($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"]));
        $dateArray = array( "age" => "$age", "birthday" => "False");
        return print_r($dateArray);
        return True;

    }
}       
}
getBirthDate("9/6/1993")
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using double `return`s one right after another?! When a `return` code is executed, php will stop executing rest of the function.

Comment: See, you're getting downvotes because you haven't explained what you need help with.

Comment: No, you're getting downvotes because the question is neither a question nor a comprehensible statement.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I cut it off short. I edited it to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

For starts, don't use True and False, or TRUE and FALSE.

Secondly, your `return True` line is never seeing the light of day because you are returning a value right before it. Return literally stops your script at the point of a return statement.

```
return True;
```

Should be

```
return true;
```

Also, always use === operator not == when checking booleans. Any non-zero value could equate to true.

```
$true = true;

if ($true === true) {
    echo 'Yes! I got a true boolean result';
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me and the if statement is still not processing correctly